# Identical strings not equal in PHP

Tags: php

```
class VocabularyValidator
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->check('termIdenfifier');
    }

    public function check ($tst) {

        var_dump($tst);

        $a = (string)'a:termIdentifier';
        $b = sprintf('a:%s', (string)$tst);

        var_dump($a);
        var_dump($b);

        var_dump(bin2hex($a));
        var_dump(bin2hex($b));

        var_dump(strcmp($a, $b));
        var_dump($a === $b);
    }

    public static function check2 ($tst) {

        var_dump($tst);

        $a = (string)'a:termIdentifier';
        $b = sprintf('a:%s', (string)$tst);

        var_dump($a);
        var_dump($b);

        var_dump(bin2hex($a));
        var_dump(bin2hex($b));

        var_dump(strcmp($a, $b));
        var_dump($a === $b);
    }
}
```

I call this in a Controller like this:

```
VocabularyValidator::check2('termIdentifier');
new VocabularyValidator();
```

The output:

```
string 'termIdentifier' (length=14)
string 'a:termIdentifier' (length=16)
string 'a:termIdentifier' (length=16)
string '613a7465726d4964656e746966696572' (length=32)
string '613a7465726d4964656e746966696572' (length=32)
int 0
boolean true

string 'termIdenfifier' (length=14)
string 'a:termIdentifier' (length=16)
string 'a:termIdenfifier' (length=16)
string '613a7465726d4964656e746966696572' (length=32)
string '613a7465726d4964656e666966696572' (length=32)
int 14
boolean false
```

Why are identical functions giving different results?

Comment: `bin2hex($b)` is different in the second function (66 instead of 74 halfway the string). That is pretty clear when you put them underneath each other. Slightly less clear is the typo it came from. One of the `t`s is upside down. ;-)

Comment: Yeah I noticed the hex difference, but was somehow convinced some weird was going on instead of a typo..brainfart i guess

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have a typo `termIdentifier` !== `termIdenfifier`

```
$this->check('termIdenfifier');
```

Comment: omg I completely overlooked it during an hour of debugging..will accept answer when SO lets me

Comment: @Oli a better alternative would be to just delete the question. A typo fix isn't useful for anyone else. It'll be closed and deleted in time anyway, so you might as well cut the process short and avoid wasting more people's time.

Comment: It won't let me delete it now that it's been answered.